# How to display the serial number CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. My issue is, I am not getting series number in the function. I am getting only n=1 and it continues displaying only 1. I don't want to use one more each condition there.

So I am getting output is

```
Sr_no     | Name
1         | MNBV
1         | lkjhg
1         | lkjh
```

I need output like

```
Sr_no     | Name
1         | MNBV
2         | lkjhg
3         | lkjh
```

**Controller**

```
foreach($order_list as $order) { 
if(is_array($order)){
      foreach($order as $r) {
        $data1[]=$this->order_access_list($r); //calling function
          }
    }
    else{
$data1[]=$this->order_access_list($order); //calling function
    }
}
```

**function**

```
public function order_access_list($val) {
$n=1;
$data = array("Sr_No" => $n,
              "Name"=>$val->c_firstname."".$val->c_lastname
              );
               $n++;
return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable `$n` in your function as `static` so that it retains its value between calls i.e.

```
public function order_access_list($val) {
    static $n=1;
    $data = array("Sr_No" => $n,
                  "Name"=>$val->c_firstname."".$val->c_lastname
                  );
    $n++;
    return $data;
}
```

See the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).